# Store a token in windows phone 8.1 - LocalSettings not working

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I'm facing a big problem in my WP8.1 app.

I'm trying to store a token that I receive from an API in a LocalSettings.

```
  var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

  localSettings.Values["token"] = token;
```

then to access the token :

```
  string token = (string)Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["token"];
```

But when I'm shutting down the application and start it again, the localSettings["token"] is empty (the token variable is not empty for sure) .

I need to do that to see if the user is logged in my application to redirect him directly to the Menu and not the login page.

I'm working on Emulator.
Thanks by advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure token ain't empty when storing it?

When getting the token from your LocalSettings, you might want to be sure the key ain't empty as well. (So you can use a backup plan)

```
var localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
if (localSettings.Values.ContainsKey("token"))
{
    string text = (string)localSettings.Values["token"];
}
else
{
    // ...
}
```